# How to send email to user upon change in a certain column in SharePoint online list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a sharepoint list to submit requests for a task to be done. In each item there will be assigned a certain person to that task. I want this certain person to be emailed upon having that item status changed to "Accept" or "Reject". So based on the "Status" column, I want the person in the "Engineer" column to be emailed about a change to the status of the item they are a part of...

Comment: Try creating a Flow on that Library. There should be a template available

Comment: @Colbs there is but only for Creating AND Modifying an item, I need for just modifying a certain column of an item

Comment: @aNobleNoob One more thing. I assume you use content approval in SharePoint for the approval status( in fact, flow can do that for you)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Power App for this purpose. Try to create a Custom Form For the List And Change the Behaviour For On submit/save.
You can check the form values before saving it and if specific field changed Do whatever you want. You can easily initiate a Flow from power app if a specific field changed.

Comment: I have zero knowledge of PowerApps but I created the form and am at the Submit/Save button, what would I input in the formula to start the workflow?

Comment: You need to create some variables before running the Flow. If you are new to Power app you can see a complete tutorial which explains how to track field change in PowerApps [link](https://wonderlaura.com/2018/04/19/powerapps-notify-on-field-change/) You Also need to run Ms Flow from Power app, [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/using-logic-flows) you can find Microsoft Documents on how to do This. Combining these two Link You should be able to archive your request.

Answer (score 0):

For content approval status is not integrated with flow, you will need to use call HTTP request to get the approval status and then send the email in flow.

Please have a check in this article: https://prairiedeveloper.com/2018/12/microsoft-flow-determine-the-approval-status-of-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-item/

So the process will be like, set trigger to be when a list item is created/modified>get approval status>make an if condition to check whether approve or reject and then send email to the engineer.

Besides, you can also use those approval flow templates using Flow approval action to send the approval request directly in Flow instead of using content approval